# How to reduce download time

Tags: perl

Our application has to download 800 images within 30 secs, but even if we increase time for 1 min, our application is still not able to download all the images.

How can we increase the download speed? so that we can download 800 images within 30 secs?
Is it possible?

Could someone please suggest.

Comment: Reduce the size of the images? Buy a faster internet connection?

Comment: Not enough information.  What code are you using to download the images?  What speed network connection do you have?  What is the total size of the images?

Answer (score 5):

Are you downloading the images one at a time, waiting for the first to finish before requesting the second? It might complete faster if you start multiple downloads in parallel (but not too many!).

Answer (score 3):

If the speed is not limited by your internet connection physically, try to use multiple threads/processes. This is how mass-downloaders work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this on your end.  You need a faster network connection or the images you are downloading must be smaller.  (If it were possible to speed up downloads from the user's side, there would never be lag in online games.)

Comment: As an application developer, is there any way that I can improve performance of my network speed?

Comment: especially if they are in JPEG...

Comment: No.  Networks are based on both hardware and software. If you have a 10 megabit connection, you have a 10 megabit connection.

Comment: You can't speed up any individual download, but you can speed up the overall process by downloading multiple files in parallel so that data can be received on one while waiting for another. If you only do one at a time, your bottleneck will usually be latency rather than bandwidth. Of course, there's still a (usually low) limit to how many files you can download in parallel before either bandwidth becomes the bottleneck or you hit the server's limit on per-client concurrent connections, so I'm still skeptical about pulling off 800 files in 30 seconds, even in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the images into a ZIP file.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading multiple resources parallelly could reduce download time significantly. [`fork`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) can be used for parallel execution.

Have a look at [`Parallel::ForkManager`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel%3a%3aForkManager) which will help you accomplish the task at hand easily. The *DESCRIPTION* section in the POD of the module provides an example of a downloader.

Based on your system configuration, you will have to experiment to determine the maximum number of parallel processes. Too less or too many processes can affect performance.

Factors which will affect performance are:

- CPU speed
- CPU scheduler
- Memory
- Network speed
- Network congestion